# Unable to create a Linked Integration Runtime

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have 2 Data Factories, a VM, and a SQL Server. I am attempting to set up a Linked Self-Hosted IR on Data Factory B to connected to the Self-Hosted IR being used by Data Factory A. I go through the steps listed in the Microsoft Documentation and assign the Linked SHIR a unique name and give it the Resource ID for SHIR on Data Factory A. I'm using a managed identity that has contributor permissions on Data Factory A, and the SHIR on Data Factory A has Data Factory B listed under sharing. There are also no additional firewalls set up in Azure for either Data Factory.

However, when I click "Create", I get the error:

> Failed to save [Linked IR]. Error: Failed to save integration runtime. The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.DataFactory' within the specified time period.

I have tried giving Data Factory B different permissions, and tried setting up the Linked IR with a different account as well as used different browsers to no avail.

Comment: It seems that the issue is related to the communication between the Linked Self-Hosted IR on Data Factory B and the Self-Hosted IR on Data Factory A. 

can you check the network connectivity between the two Data Factories and the SHIR. if you have any Vnet and subnets, please make sure to allow connections comming from the subnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on this, it looks like the Data Factory that was having the issue (Data Factory B) was set up incorrectly somehow. I ended up recreating the pipeline on Data Factory A and didn't have any issues.

Still unsure what exactly the issue was, but this solved the problem nonetheless.